# Ruby removing non numeric values from array and converting rest to float

Tags: arrays, ruby, each

I have a user entered string that I turn into an array, then I iterate through the array and remove non number values.

It looks like my regex match is working half the time and my to_f never sets the array value to a float.

> Lets assume I enter: "1 2 3b c3 4, 5t"

```
puts "Enter Minutes"  
STDOUT.flush  
freq = gets.chomp
freq = freq.split(/\W/) #this creates the array, splitting at non-word chars

p freq #outputs: ["1", "2", "3b", "c3", "4", "", "5t"]

freq.each do |minutes|
        if ( minutes == "" or /\D/.match(minutes) ) then freq.delete(minutes) else minutes.to_f end
end

p freq #outputs: ["1", "2", "c3", "4", "5t"]
```

> My desired results are: [1, 2, 4] #note they are numeric not chars

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you're mutating freq only in the `then` condition and not in the else condition.

There are enumerable methods that mutate for you, they usually end with a `!`:

```
freq = ["1", "2", "3b", "c3", "4", "", "5t"]
=> ["1", "2", "3b", "c3", "4", "", "5t"]

freq.reject! { |minutes| minutes.match(/\D/) || minutes == "" }.map! { |minutes| minutes.to_f }
=> [1.0, 2.0, 4.0]
```

Comment: Thank you. is .map advised over .each?

Comment: @seamus you can do any iteration-related logic using each but if you are making some use of the return value of the each block, it's more idiomatic to use other enumerable methods like map, reduce/each_with_object/select/reject/all?/any?/find/etc You can see the full list of methods here https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html

Answer (score 4):

```
arr = ["1", "2", "3b", "c3", "4", "", "5t"]
```

There are two possible approaches to this problem. One is to perform two steps: remove all elements that are not representations of non-negative integers, then convert those integers to floats, requiring one pass through each of two arrays. The other is to build an array of floats, making a single pass through `arr`. That can be done as follows.

```
arr.each_with_object([]) { |s,a| a << s.to_f if s.match?(/\A\d+\z/) }
  #=> [1.0, 2.0, 4.0]
```

The regular expression reads, "match the beginning of the string (the anchor `\A`), followed by one or more digits, followed by the end of the string (the anchor `\z`). That's the same as not matching an empty string or a character that is not a digit, so we could instead write:

```
arr.each_with_object([]) { |s,a| a << s.to_f unless s.empty? or s.match?(/\D/) }
  #=> [1.0, 2.0, 4.0]
```

There is not much to choose between the two here, but sometimes the latter approach is easier to implement.

Another way, that I'm not overly fond of (but it's worth knowing about), is to use the method [Kernel#Float](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-Float) followed by [Array#compact](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-compact):

```
arr = ["1", "-2", "3b", "c3", "4.23", "", "5t", "-1.2e3"]

arr.map { |s| Float(s) rescue nil }.compact
  #=> [1.0, -2.0, 4.23, -1200.0]
```

As seen, this converts elements of `arr` that are representations of integers or floats (not just non-negative integers) to floats (which may or may not be wanted).

`Float(s)` raises an `ArgumentError` if `s` cannot be converted to a float. For example:

```
Float("3b")
  #=> ArgumentError (invalid value for Float(): "3b")
```

When that happens I catch the exception in an *in-line rescue clause*, returning `nil`.

Some Rubiests don't like in-line rescue clauses because they can mask other errors. That concern can be addressed by only rescuing `ArgumentErrors`:

```
arr.map do |s|
  begin
    Float(s)
  rescue ArgumentError
    nil
  end
end.compact
  #=> [1.0, -2.0, 4.23, -1200.0]
```

Comment: Your post is giving the feel of reading a good article. Thanks for detailing clearly.